# How to remove existing ip tunnel

Tags: linux, centos, tunnel

I create ip tunnel in centos linux with this link http://www.techonia.com/create-tunnel-interface-linux.

Then I want to delete the existing tunnel, I think I have already delete with command ip tunnel del "device".  But why the port is still cannot be accessed? or maybe I am wrong when do the deletion?  the port i used for tunneling before is 1433 (sql server).

Comment: It's ok.  I think I have deleted it.  But port 1433 still cannot be used... anyone knows?

Comment: This is sysadmin related and my first Google returned good results. Belongs on another forum.

Answer (score 4):

Please try these commands:

```
ifconfig $tunnel_id down
iptunnel del $tunnel_id
```